# Изменить тип письма woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, сервер, woocommerce, email

Нужно изменить тип отправляемого письма после заказа. На локальном сервере(apache) у меня есть три опции Plain text, HTML, Multipart. На поддомене для разработки только одна опция Plain text. После часов поиска наткнулся на информацию, что это может быть что-то в настройках сервера. Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После переноса магазина столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Решение - поставить расширение PHP `php-xml`:

`# sudo apt install php-xml`

Перед установкой не забудьте проверить свою версию php, используемую для этого сайта. Если она отличается от той, что установлена в системе по умолчанию, нужно явно указать, расширение к какой версии php нужно установить. Например, для 7.3 нужно установить пакет `php7.3-xml`